# Razor-pages error 500 OnPost method while try to bind model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've got strange issue in my Razor-Pages project.

I've got simple page:

```cs
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    public Model Model { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
 
    public void OnPost()
    {
    }
}
```

cshtml:

```
@page
@model TestModel

<form method="post">
    <div class="row">
        @(Html.TextAreaFor(d => d.Model.Description))
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now, when I try to pass model as parameter to OnPost method

```
public void OnPost(Model model){}
```

or try to bind it by

```
[BindProperty]
public Model Model { get; set; }
```

the code is not executing OnPost method and throw error 500 instead.
It's weird, because on the other page it works.
What can be the reason? How can I investigate deeper that problem?

Comment: The client send data in a body (request) when you use POST.  The server receives the request with the data using a GET.  Then a server send a response with a body using a POST.  The client receives the response using a GET.

Comment: What is the error details?

Comment: @mj1313 I can't tell it now because I don't remember. I just removed this file, created new one and it started to work. It's really weird that sometimes I need to create new file and paste all the code (and it's working well there) from file where the error appears.